# Azure mobile service send push notification to specific userId

Tags: azure, push-notification

How do I push notification to a speficic userId in Azure. No custom API if possible.

```
push.apns.send(null, {
    alert: "Alert: " + item.text,
    payload: {
        inAppMessage: "Test notification: '" + item.text + "'"
    }
});
```

}, 2500);

Please shed some light.